# How to implement imagecopy (GD) function by Imagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, imagick

I'm working with imagick and face some problem. I want to composite two images: image01 and image02,image01 is background image,a part of image02 composite on image01. the function just like GD's [imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) function.

```
bool imagecopy( resource dst_im, resource src_im, int dst_x, int dst_y, 
                int src_x, int src_y,int src_w, int src_h )
```

> Copy a part of src_im onto dst_im starting at the x,y coordinates
>   src_x, src_y with a width of src_w and a height of src_h. The portion
>   defined will be copied onto the x,y coordinates, dst_x and dst_y.

the question is: how to implement imagecopy function by Imagick?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
//load files from source
$background = new Imagick(image01_src);
$overlay = new Imagick(image02_src);

//Crop the overlay to the required size
$overlay->cropImage ($new_width,$new_height,$x_offset,$y_offset);

//composite overlay on background
$background->compositeImage($overlay, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $margin_x, $margin_y);

//save result
$background->setImageFormat("png");
$background->writeImage(new_src);

//clean up
$background->clear();
$background->destroy();
$overlay->clear();
$overlay->destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [composite](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php), for example:

```
$large_image->compositeImage($small_image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $margin_x, $margin_y);
```

If you show me the source and final pictures, I can give you the exact code.